# Creating a module and giving it config parameters options

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, module-params, module-manager

on the documentation for creating a module, the basic is all there but they don't talk about giving parameters to your module.

Example the color of the background or the size whatever.

So I want to know is there any documentation about creating a form that gives this parameters by the admin after installing the module.

My module is basically complete in a way but I want the user to be able to customize it.

I know my question doesnt have code involve. But I've been told to come here if I have questions about joomla since i'm rather new to this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to JSE.

I'm not sure which documentation you've been referring to, however the Joomla Docs show you how to add parameters to your module:

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Adding_Form_Fields

So a basic example:

**mod_something.xml**

```
<config>
  <fields name="params">
    <fieldset name="basic">
        <field name="size" type="text" default="20px" label="Size" />
        <field name="background" type="color" default="#eee" format="hex" label="Background" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset name="advanced">
        <field name="param3" type="text" default="something" label="Param 3" />
        <field name="param4" type="text" default="something" label="Param 4" />
    </fieldset>
  </fields>
</config>
```

Note; I've added another `fieldset` which will show you how to separate your parameters under different tabs.

**Accessing the parameters (Views):**

```
$size = $params->get('size');
$background = $params->get('background');

$param3 = $params->get('param3');
$param4 = $params->get('param4');
```

**Accessing the parameters (Helper):**

```
class ModSomethingHelper
{
    private $params = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->params = $this->getParams();
    }

    public function getParams()
    {
        $module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_something');
        $moduleParams = new JRegistry;

        if ($module->params !== '')
        {
            $moduleParams->loadString($module->params);
        }

        return $moduleParams;
    }

    // Non-Static function example
    public function yourFunction()
    {
        $this->params->get('size');
    }

    // Static function example
    public static function yourStaticFunction()
    {
        $helper = new ModSomethingHelper();

        $size = $helper->getParams()->get('size');
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote you .thank you so much for the fast reply. I appreciate it! So I can put multilple fields in the same fieldset?

Comment: You're more than welcome. Yes, you can put as many as you want in there. You can also create a separate `fieldset` which will create a new tab for you. I've updated my example above to show you.

Comment: Perfect that works . Last question sorry to bother you again. The way you access the parameter like that would be only in the Module Entry Point? Or I would be able to access them on my helper.php too?

Comment: No worries. Not in the helper. I'll update my answer with the code for that

Comment: @engjellbislimi - I've updated the answer showing you how to get them in a static and non-static function

Comment: So with all of this my custom parameters would saved? thanks man you've been a big help.

Comment: Yup, Joomla will automatically save all the parameters you add to your XML file ;)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. When I enter the colors I want and I do save & close right after. the colors doesn't save at all..? and it seems like my parameters aren't even receiving it.

Comment: Hmm, I'd have to see some code. Can you please create a new question and add as much relevant code as possible so it can be debugged?

Comment: I just did @lodder